# Try to recover media stream of Chromecast, but blocked by payload type

Tags: webrtc, chromecast

Captured packets from Nexus 7 to Chromecast while doing screen mirroring, but failed to recover media stream from captured packets.

Checked the detailed content in packet：

```
10.. .... = Version: RFC 1889 Version (2)
..0. .... = Padding: False
...0 .... = Extension: False
.... 0000 = Contributing source identifiers count: 0
0... .... = Marker: False

Payload type: DynamicRTP-Type-127 (127)
Sequence number: 11150
Timestamp: 11419287
Synchronization Source identifier: 0x00000001 (1)
Payload: 818e0000000004020064fff14c802ba00021114500145001...
```

Another stream marked with payload type 96. In rfc 3551, it only says "dynamic" for encoding type. (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3551#page-33)

Does anyone knows details of Chromecast media stream? Is it VP8?
(If it is VP8, then payload type should be something like 100 or 116 according to this page: http://www.webrtc.org/testing/analyze-packets-using-wireshark)

thanks!

Comment: also checked RFC 1889 Version (2), didn't find definitions.

Comment: Are you not able to capture the connection negotiation? It could also be Vp9 or H264(which could be many payload types given the parameters)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is proprietary and encrypted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This does provide an answer; my answer clearly states that it is proprietary and that the payload is encrypted.

Comment: Hi, Ali, glad to see you again, and I do appreciate your answer, it's very clear to me.

Comment: And, Ali, so there is no way for me to recover this video from packets captured, right? .........Then is it possible for me to add some codes in webRTC (this part is open source) to save a copy of unencrypted video on local disc? I'm asking this because I duplicated the video from Chromecast HDMI output, and now want to make a comparison to what my android device sent out. It's for my master student research, not any business purpose. Thanks!

Comment: Dave, you cannot recover the content by capturing packets and it is not based on WebRTC either.

Comment: @AliNaddaf. That was an auto-generated comment, so don't take it too literally. Your question was flagged as being low-quality, because it was so short. If you want to avoid this, just provide a little more explanation. As the other comments show, it would have proved helpful in this case (and probably even more so to future users). As the SO help says: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better".

Comment: @AliNaddaf   Thanks Ali. I think that's the final answer, I give up. But may I ask what's the usage of payload type 127? According to my capture, payload type 96 should be media stream because if I just mirror a static screen without any change, payload type 96 packets is almost 0, while it could be very large if I touch screen to change content view. But payload type 127 packets is always there. Is it for heart-beating? Or for remote control?..... Thanks~！

Answer (score 1):

If it's using WebRTC for this (and last I knew it was, but that may have well have changed), the info on the type of data is in the SDP which is exchanged over encrypted channels (i.e. you can't read it).  Secondarily, WebRTC traffic is all encrypted with DTLS-SRTP (i.e. you can't read more than the header of the RTP packets anyways).

tl;dr: no, you can't do that.